# How to resolve libpcre.so.1()(64bit) dependency in amazon linux ami

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, perl, rhel, maxscale

When try to install maxscale, it ask libpcre. How to install libpcre
on linux?

```
rpm -ivh maxscale-1.4.3-1.rhel.7.x86_64.rpm
warning: maxscale-1.4.3-1.rhel.7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 8167ee24: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
       libpcre.so.1()(64bit) is needed by maxscale-1.4.3-1.x86_64
```

Comment: Have you tried using `yum` yet?

Comment: i tried using yum install libaio but it doesn't fulfill the dependency. i tried installing the pcre pcre-8.37-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm and instlling it but it doesn;t work as well.

Comment: Did you get past this?

Comment: After some days of searching and try many thigs. my attempt was to copy the library `libpcre.so.1` from an distribution that have it and copy into amazonlinux:1 (who was the AMI that I was using) and I still have the error. I desist the library instalation.

Comment: For my specific case (I was building a package for amazonlinux:1), I go to my building scripts and remove the packages that requires that library, in order to generate my `.rpm` package without the need of the library. Wasn't great, I have to admit but it is what it is. Also take in mind that `amazonlinux:1` it is close to be down, so try to go into a more recent AMI or distribution.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```sh
yum install pcre2-devel.x86_64
```